# Can't properly use NSEventModifierFlags in Swift 2.0

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, swift2

I'm trying to develop a little Mac app in Xcode 7 (7A120f), but it isn't letting me. Allegedly, this code snippet is faulty:

```
let composeHotKey = DDHotKey(keyCode: UInt16(kVK_Return), modifierFlags: NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask | NSEventModifierFlags.ShiftKeyMask, task: {
    event in

    self.doSomething()
})
```

Trying to compile my app results in an Xcode build failure with the following error message while it highlights the `NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask | NSEventModifierFlags.ShiftKeyMask` part:

> Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to two NSEventModifierFlags operands

What's going on? According to everything I find online, I should be able to do that.

Comment: I don't have a Mac handy to check with, but this is probably a case of `NSEventModifierFlags` being imported to Swift as an `OptionSetType`. Those don't use bit-twiddling syntax like in C (or Swift 1.x)... try a set literal instead: `modifierFlags: [ .CommandKeyMask, .ShiftKeyMask ]`

Comment: That was totally the problem, thanks for the solution! Can you repost this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift 2, bit field style enums like `NSEventModifierFlags` are imported to Swift as subtypes of `OptionSetType`. Those don't use bit-twiddling syntax like in C (or Swift 1.x).

Instead, such types use methods and syntax reflecting set logic. You can create one with a set literal:

```
let composeHotKey = DDHotKey(keyCode: UInt16(kVK_Return), modifierFlags: .CommandKeyMask.rawValue | .ShiftKeyMask.rawValue, task: {
    event in

    self.doSomething()
})
```

Comment: I had to make a few modifications to DDHotKey's initializer, as it expected a UInt instead of NSEventModifierFlags, but everything's working now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSEventModifierFlags(rawValue: NSEventModifierFlags.NumericPadKeyMask.rawValue | NSEventModifierFlags.NumericPadKeyMask.rawValue)
```